# Referencing two excel workbook in different directories at the same time using the DIR function

Tags: excel, vba

I am trying to copy and paste some sheets from an excel file in one folder to a sheet in an excel file in another folder using VBA on a Mac. I having problem referencing both the directory at the same time using `Dir()`. The following is the structure of my code.

```
fileDir_copy = Application.ActiveWorkbook.Path & "\input\"
fileDir_paste = Application.ActiveWorkbook.Path & "\output\"
fileCriteria = "*.xlsx"

fileName_copy = Dir(fileDir_copy & fileCriteria)
fileName_paste = Dir(fileDir_paste & fileCriteria)

Do While Len(fileName_copy) > 0
   set wb_copy = Workbooks.Open(fileDir_copy & fileName_copy)

   Do While Len(fileName_paste) > 0
       set wb_paste = Workbooks.Open(fileDir_copy & fileName_paste)
       '''''
       'Copy Paste work

       '''''
       wb_paste.Close True
   fileName_paste = Dir()
   Loop

wb_copy.Close True
'Error on the line below
fileName_copy = Dir()
Loop
```

I get an error saying Run-time error '5': Invalid procedure call or argument, and the line marked in the code gets highlighted.

Comment: You can't nest calls to `Dir()` - only one loop can run at a time.

Comment: What's the relationship between each input and its corresponding output file?  How do you make sure the correct content goes to the correct output file?

Comment: So, the first two characters of the input file name are the same as the first two characters of the output file name. I haven't shown that in my code. And the number of files is the same in both folders.

Comment: And using Dir() is the only alternative to FileSystemObject on mac I know off

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe something like this...

```vb
Sub TestIt()
    Dim fileDir_copy As String, fileDir_paste As String, fileCriteria As String
    Dim wb_copy As Workbook, wb_paste As Workbook
    Dim copyNames As Collection, pasteNames As Collection, f
    
    fileDir_copy = Application.ActiveWorkbook.Path & "\input\"
    fileDir_paste = Application.ActiveWorkbook.Path & "\output\"
    fileCriteria = "*.xlsx"
    
    Set copyNames = FileMatches(fileDir_copy, fileCriteria)
    If copyNames.Count = 0 Then Exit Sub 'no files found
    
    For Each f In copyNames
        Set wb_copy = Workbooks.Open(f)
        'any output match?
        Set pasteNames = FileMatches(fileDir_paste, _
                               Left(wb_copy.Name, 2) & fileCriteria)

        If pasteNames.Count = 1 Then  'single matched file?
            Set wb_paste = Workbooks.Open(pasteNames(1))
            
            'do whatever is needed with these two files
            
            wb_paste.Close True
            
        Else
            MsgBox "Found " & pasteNames.Count & " matches for " & _
               Left(wb_copy.Name, 2) & fileCriteria, vbExclamation
        End If
        wb_copy.Close True
    Next f
    
End Sub

'Return a collection of file paths from `fldr` where the file
'  names matches `pattern`
Function FileMatches(fldr As String, pattern As String) As Collection
    Dim rv As New Collection, f
    f = Dir(fldr, vbNormal)
    Do While Len(f) > 0
        If f Like pattern Then rv.Add fldr & f
        f = Dir()
    Loop
    Set FileMatches = rv
End Function
```

Worth noting - I don't think you can use wildcards with `Dir()` on a Mac.